# Finding the most similar communities between the 2 graphs

Tags: python, igraph

I have applied Louvain community detection on 2 different graphs with the **same set of vertices**. I want to find similar communities between the two graphs and then remove those vertices belonging to these communities. Is there any method to find the most similar communities in igraph or any other python library?

Comment: What's the measure for "similarity"?

Comment: @ThomasIsCoding The graphs are both undirected and unweighted, and the vertices are labeled (e.g. from 1 to 1000). The label of the vertices and the way they are connected to each other is important. Similar communities should look like each other in terms of their labels and their connections.